# How can I revert zip files which are zipped using "gzip -r"

Tags: linux, gzip

I intended to zip a directory, so I used:

```
gzip -r myfolder
```

When I checked the output, it has been zipped all the files within the directory and its subdirectories. It wasn't what I explected

How can I unzip these so many zipped files to their original state?

Comment: Simply try to execute `gunzip -r myfolder` to decompress any `.gz` file found in `myfolder`'s directory, including any subdirectory.
Then try `zip -r myfolder` or `tar -czf myfolder.tar.gz myfolder` to create a single archive file containing everything in `myfolder` directory.

Comment: @Jaleks Thanks, however it seems `zip -r myfolder` do nothing

Comment: Sry, `zip -r myfolder.zip myfolder` would be it…